# Overriding Symfony FileSystem's tempnam() method

Tags: symfony, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php

I'm trying to run Symfony 2.8 on Google App Engine. Symfony 2.8 added their own version of tempnam(), see [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L484), which won't work properly on App Engine because it doesn't recognize the `gs://` scheme.

I've written a working patch here:

```
 if (null === $scheme || 'file' === $scheme || 'gs' === $scheme) {
      $tmpFile = tempnam($hierarchy, $prefix);

      // If tempnam failed or no scheme return the filename otherwise prepend the scheme
      if (false !== $tmpFile) {
          if (null !== $scheme && 'gs' !== $scheme) {
              return $scheme.'://'.$tmpFile;

          }

          return $tmpFile;
      }

      throw new IOException('A temporary file could not be created.');
  }
```

but I don't know how to enable this without writing code in core classes.

Any help?